# How to run Android UI Tests and pass arguments to the App/Activity

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I want to run UI tests for Android app with some predefined data which will vary depending on the test case. In iOS, it's possible to pass arguments to the tested app like this:

```
app = XCUIApplication()
app.reset()
app.launchArguments += ["--myArgument"]
app.launch()
```

These arguments are later available inside the app process.

Is there something similar for Android UI testing? Best way would to access these arguments via intent's extras.

```
getIntent().getExtras().getString(key)
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it turned out it's quite simple to simulate launch arguments with `Intents`. In Android UI tests when using `ActivityTestRule` it's possible to start an activity with a specific `Intent`.

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityRule
        = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class, false, false);

Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("specificArgument", argumentValue);
activityRule.launchActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is in Kotlin. I put the intent instructions in the `@Before` method of the test.

```
@Rule
@JvmField
var mActivityTestRule = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java, false, false)

@Before
fun setupTestConfiguration() {
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.putExtra("mocked", true)
    mActivityTestRule.launchActivity(intent)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With new ActivityScenario you can launch Activity with intent the following way:

```kotlin
    val intent = Intent(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext, YourActivity::class.java).apply {
        putExtra("EXTRA_KEY, extraValue)
    }

    val scenario = launchActivity<YourActivity>(intent)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using espresso for Android UI testing.
https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso

Comment: It has nothing to do with my question.